# If $y=\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}$ ,prove: $0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{10}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

We know that:
$$y=\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}$$
Then we have to prove that:
$$0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{10}$$
How to use what we obtain from first fraction to prove what it wanted? Do you have an easy idea?

Answer (score 9):

Hint: We have $$0\le (x^2-5)^2$$ and by expanding $$10x^2\le x^4+25$$ so $$\frac{10x^2}{x^4+25}\le 1$$

Answer (score 5):

Since $x^2\ge 0$ and $x^4+25>0$ we have

$$y=\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}\ge 0$$

and since $y$ is bounded above

$$\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}\le k \implies kx^4-x^2+25k \ge 0$$

$$\Delta=1-100k^2=0 \implies k=\frac1{10}$$

Comment: Thanks @gimusi a lot! I had another similiar question like the above! May I ask it here and let us do not ask same questios. It's simple just hint me.

Comment: @user602338 You can ask another OP, it is preferable than discuss that by comments. If you want only a hint you should make it clear when formulating the OP. Otherwise we can discuss it in chat.

Comment: $$x>0$$ then prove that $$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$$. Any hints @gimusi?

Comment: @user602338 That's a classical inequality. Just multiply by x RHS and LHS. Why we can do that?

Comment: @user602338 Multiply both sides by $x$ since $x>0$ and the inequality holds "its way".

Comment: @Rebellos He was looking for a hint! :(

Comment: @gimusi I'm blind. Edited :P

Comment: @user602338 The key point is that we can multiply by $x$ without change the inequality because $x>0$

Comment: @Rebellos Thanks! :)

Comment: @gimusi thanks a lot .thanks for explains :D

Comment: @user602338 You are welcome. Do not be afraid to ask questions on that by new OP. The important thing is that you show your work and effort and explain what are your doubs on that.

Comment: Prove the AM GM theorem on your own once.  $a + b \ge 2\sqrt{ab} \iff (\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \ge 0$ and step back and.... marvel at how useful it is  $x + \frac 1x \ge 2 \iff x -2 +\frac 1x \ge 0 \iff x - 2\sqrt{x\frac 1x} + \frac 1x \ge 0$.  Replace $x$ with $y^2$ and $\frac 1x$ with $z^2$ and you get.....

Answer (score 5):

From the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we have

$$\begin{align}
x^4+25&\ge  2\sqrt{25x^4}\\\\
&=10x^2\tag1
\end{align}$$

Applying $(1)$ reveals

$$0\le \frac{x^2}{x^4+25}\le \frac{x^2}{10x^2}=\frac1{10}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 4):

$x^2, x^4, x^4 + 25 \ge 0$ so $\frac {x^2}{x^4 + 25} \ge 0$.

If $x = 0$ then $\frac {x^2}{x^4 + 25} = 0 < \frac 1{10}$.

If $x \ne 0$ then $\frac {x^2}{x^4 + 25} \le \frac 1{10}\iff \frac {x^4 + 25}{x^2} \ge 10$.

And by AM-GM... $\frac {x^4 + 25}{x^2}  = x^2 + \frac {25}{x^2} \ge 2\sqrt{x^2*\frac {25}{x^2}}= 2\sqrt{25} =10$.

....  But perhaps the most direct way as all terms are positive.

$\frac {x^2}{x^4 + 25} \le \frac 1{10} \iff 10x^2  \le x^4 + 25 \iff x^4 -10x^2 + 25=(x^2 -5)^2 \ge 0$.  which must be true as $(x^2 - 5)^2$ is a perfect square.

[Note:  the second argument is essentially replicating a prove of the AM-GM: Namely for positive $a,b$ we know $a + b \ge 2\sqrt{ab}\iff a-2\sqrt{ab} + b = (\sqrt a - \sqrt b) \ge 0$  which.... must be true.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}=\le\frac1{10}\iff x^4-10x^2+25\ge0$$

Can you now factor the rightmost expression and prove the inequality is true?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^4+25}\implies f'(x)=-\frac{2 x \left(x^4-25\right)}{\left(x^4+25\right)^2}\implies f''(x)=\frac{2 \left(3 x^8-300 x^4+625\right)}{\left(x^4+25\right)^3}$$ The first derivative cancels at $x=0$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum. Thos other roots are $x_\pm=\pm \sqrt 5$ which corresponds to maximum values of the function. Now, compute $f(\pm \sqrt 5)$ to get the result.